# flash as3 Getting a string var value and putting it in a input-text box

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I know for a start this isn't much, but I'm very lost and frustrated lol.  Below is some code on a mc.  as3 is on frame 2 layer a, scrolll(input-text) is on same frame 2 layer b. I tried to simply everything until I could get something working, but no luck. Does this look ok below; please ask for more information if needed.
Thanks
Terry

```
//input-text with instance name scrolll within mc... bible.scrolll,  works when I set it to static 
//text and put some text
this.scrolll.text = "help";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. you have a MovieClip called bible that is on the timeline and a child of its is an input-text field?
Well from within the timeline this.bible.scrolll.text="help"; should work just fine, and I see that your forgot the .bible in your code so maybe this is the issue.
Please comment if this does not work and "accept" the answer if it does.